# What is the best implementation of an infinitescroll to a collectionview? Like Pinterest which at the end of the scroll fetches the data

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've done it but I'm not quite satisfied with it because I get this error when I try to scroll  fast.  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x14e85a50> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Comment: I'm seeing this error in collection views in iOS 7, but not iOS 6.

Comment: When I implement a button to fetch data it works fine without this error even If I push the button real fast.  I don't get the error plus my collection view updates fine.  But the problem comes in if I triggered it on the scroll. I wanted to achieve what Pinterest is doing.  I tried scrollViewDidEndDecelerating methods that suggest it but still doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's some apple sample code for scroll views, should give you an idea about how to go about this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Nope sorry this is not it.

Comment: Well you didn't give us much to go on, but the best practices regarding what you want to do are in that sample. The error you're getting means you are changing the value(s) of objects in your NSSet whilst also trying to read those objects.

Comment: Not exactly.  What I wanted to do is like the Pinterest scroll.

Comment: Ok I'll check what you mean. Thanks!